# Cannot Install RMySQL on CENTOS

Tags: r, linux, centos5, rmysql

I am finding it very difficult to install the "RMySQL" package on CENTOS.

```
install.packages("RMySQL", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
```

The error it is throwing me is:

```
* installing *source* package ‘RMySQL’ ...
** package ‘RMySQL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lmysqlclient
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libmysqlclient was not found. Try installing:
* deb: libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu 16.04)
    libmariadbclient-dev (Ubuntu 14.04)
* rpm: mariadb-devel | mysql-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
* csw: mysql56_dev (Solaris)
* brew: mariadb-connector-c (OSX)
If libmysqlclient is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libmysqlclient.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RMySQL’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib64/R/library/RMySQL’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpbFMPmO/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("RMySQL", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") :
installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have already installed `yum update mysql-devel` but still get the same error.
Any help will be appreciated as I have been trying to figure his out since last 2 days.

Comment: Have you tried "set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually" as the error message suggests?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what they actually mean. I know that is what is causing the problems, but don't know how to solve it

Comment: It seems to be a common issue for CentOS users. Some users suggest downloading the DBI and RMySQL packages from CRAN, then installing from the command line (DBI first) `sudo R CMD INSTALL <file.tar.gz>` - https://koolinus.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/how-to-install-rmysql-on-centos/.

Comment: I just tried that DBI was successful but not RMySQL

Comment: OK. The INCLUDE_DIR is the directory that contains `mysql.h`. The LIB_DIR is the directory that contains `libmysqlclient.so.*` where * is a number. So try to locate those files on your system. LIB_DIR may be, for example, `/usr/lib/mysql`, `/usr/local/lib/mysql`, `/usr/lib64/mysql` or `/usr/local/lib64/mysql`.

Comment: Thank You that helped a lot. mysql.h was in different location altogether

Comment: I'm having the same issue, can you whare your solution?

Comment: So in my case I could install RMySQL from CRAN after running `sudo yum install mariadb-devel`.